# Zend Framework Installation

Tags: php, zend-framework

I get this error after finishing the Zend Installation.

> Server error!
>
> The server encountered an internal
>   error and was unable to complete your
>   request. Either the server is
>   overloaded or there was an error in a
>   CGI script.
>
> If you think this is a server error,
>   please contact the webmaster.

Comment: This isn't really a question?

Comment: what were you exactly doing? What do you mean by Zend Installation? Zend Framework doesn't have to be installed!

Comment: Look in your web server logs. It might be something like mod_rewrite not being turned on.

Comment: Indeed, looks like an apache/web server problem

Answer (score 1):

Look in your Apache `error_log` file for a more specific error.  I would guess you haven't updated `include_path` so your PHP scripts aren't finding the Zend Framework classes.

Remember that the PHP CLI often uses a different php.ini file from Apache's PHP, and also you need to restart Apache to enable changes to its php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

I would also add to double-check any .htaccess file that may be in ./public/